# Vector derivatives, what is the minimum of this matrix equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, vector-analysis

I am new to vector derivatives and trying to figure out a lot for my Machine Learning course. I have given the following:

$x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times n}$,

Let $B$ be symmetric (and pos.def.). What is the minimum of

$$(Ax -y)^T (Ax -y) + x^T Bx$$

with respect to $x$?

How can I approach this problem? I have no clue yet, however, I figured out, that $(Ax -y)^T (Ax -y) + x^T Bx \in \mathbb{R}^1$, thus a real number, isn't it? Hence $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

I looked up some derivation rules and I've got the following:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (Ax -y)^T (Ax -y) + x^T Bx = 2A^T (Ax - y) + (B + B^T) \cdot x$$

Setting $2A^T (Ax - y) + (B + B^T) \cdot x$ to $0$:

\begin{align*}
                         0 & = 2A^T (Ax - y) + (B + B^T) \cdot x\\
                         0 & = 2A^T A x - A^T y + (B + B^T) \cdot x\\
                     A^T y & = 2A^T A x + (B + B^T) \cdot x\\
(B + B^T)^{-1} \cdot A^T y & = 2A^T A x + x\\
\end{align*}

and here I am some what stuck, however, I don't know if this is the right approach

Comment: Minimum with respect to which argument?

Comment: @Didier I have no clue, its just the minimum of the whole term.

Comment: Most likely it's not the minimum with respect to both $x$ and $y$; since both terms are non-negative, that would trivially be at $x=y=0$. It seems more likely that this is a sum of two cost functions, one measuring the error in solving $Ax=y$ and the other an additional quadratic cost; if so, the task would be to find the minimum with respect to $x$. (The minimum with respect to $y$ is also trivial, $y=Ax$.)

Comment: But what does this have to do with vector derivatives? I thought this has at least to be applied.

Comment: *No clue*?? So you want people to tell you *what is the question that you are asking*? (I am wondering: is this the exact formulation of your homework?)

Comment: @Didier Sadly, yes. Guess I have to ask my professor what he means.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Unless some similar problems solved during the lectures could indicate what is going on? (Anyway, if I had to guess, I would follow @joriki's suggestion.)

Answer (score 1):

You are good until the previous-to-last equation, which reads $A^Ty=2A^TAx+(B+B^T)x$, that is $A^Ty=Cx$ where $C$ is the matrix $C=2A^TA+B+B^T$. Hence, if $C$ is invertible, 
$$
x=C^{-1}A^Ty.
$$
To show that $C$ is invertible, note that $C$ is symmetric hence it is enough to show that the associated quadratic form is definite positive, that is, that $z^TCz\gt0$ for every $z\ne0$. Now, 
$$z^TCz=2z^TA^TAz+z^TBz+z^TB^Tz=2\|Az\|^2+2z^TBz\geqslant2z^TBz,
$$ 
and, by hypothesis, $B$ is definite positive hence $z^TBz\gt0$ for every $z\ne0$, which ends the proof.